# one line only facebook like box

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am currently designing a website where there is a facebook like box embedded on it.
The default of facebook looks something like this:
[image]

But instead of that look, I want the friend's icons to appear on the same line as the like box similar to this:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea to do this one? I tried adding several styles on the css and override the class given by facebook but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The like button is generally an iframe so your styles will not affect it. Also as it is on a different domain, I'm not sure if you could even manipulate it by adding your own styling to the tr elements via javascript (setting them to display:table-cell achieves what you want) due to cross domain access issues. Finally I'm not sure if there are platform policies that would also be invalidated by doing this, which could have negative effects on your facebook intergration

Comment: I see. I guess adding a custom style to it is impossible at the moment. Thanks!